# Spring Boot/Maven property and system temp folder path

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a following property declared at my Spring Boot/Maven project:

```
@Value("${download.folder.path}")
private String downloadFolderPath;
```

where `download.folder.path` is a property declared at my `application.properties` file and at Maven profile.

Right now the property value is something like this:

```
<download.folder.path>d:/somedir</download.folder.path>
```

Everything works fine but I want to point `download.folder.path` property to default system temp folder for my tests instead of providing a real path.

Is it possible with Spring/Maven configuration?

Comment: What do you mean by "default system temp folder"? Unless there's an environment variable for this, I'm afraid it's impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use reference to java tmp dir property (check System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")) and reference the property like this

```
<download.folder.path>{java.io.tmpdir}</download.folder.path>
```

See [the reference properties here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872272/how-to-reference-another-property-in-java-util-properties)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot, check out `@TestPropertySource`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#__testpropertysource

You should be able to use that to point to `/tmp` or wherever.

Answer (score 0):

1.)Writing below in SpringBoot main class for whole application to be working :

```
System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "C:\\Users\\abcde\\Desktop\\Temp");
```

2.)While Running JUnit in Spring Boot application , I have set -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Work\TEMP in VM Arguments  and it worked for me .
[image]