# Access value in one .properties file from another .properties file

Tags: java, properties-file

Consider 2 property files:

1. abc.properties
2. bcd.properties

I need to get Strings from abc.properties in bcd.properties.
Using CompositeConfiguration I got solution but its not a generic solution in my project.Please suggest a way to do it using ResourceBundle itself.

Sharing what I have done :

```java
ResourceBundle  inStream = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bcd", Locale.US); 
  Properties test = new Properties();
  String keys = inStream.getString("Email");
  System.out.println("Result here "+keys);
        
abc.properties : 
  Email=Not a valid email address

bcd.properties : 
  include = abc.properties
  //some strings
```

Hope you got my issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872272/how-to-reference-another-property-in-java-util-properties

Comment: Hi Abhilash,this example show variable interpolation in same properties file. I need it from different property file.Thanks