# How to substitute the environment variable in the parameter defined in the .properties file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, properties

We have 2 test environments qa1 and qa2. Based on what we have defined in the Run/Debug configurations we either use qa1.properties file or qa2.properties file. We use Java, Selenium and IntelliJ IDEA IDE.
I have defined the ENV_NAME=qa2 in the qa2.properties file

Within each of these properties file we have URLs defined.
As an example in qa1.properties file we will have
LOGIN_URL=https://demo.testing.com/vp-clientlib-v1.php?env=qa1
and the same URL in qa2.properties file we will have
LOGIN_URL=https://demo.testing.com/vp-clientlib-v1.php?env=qa2

As you see, the environment is hardcoded. I am trying to substitute the ENV_NAME in the URL but haven't been successful so far. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [@Stefan D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5564903/stefan-d). Your response introduced me to variable interpolation and I was able to do further research on it.

A simple addition of the variable ENV_NAME=qa2 in the properties file did not help me with replacing the environment name in the URLS. On reading further I understood that it isnt possible substitute the placeholder. Standard properties files are just key-value pairs.

[OscarRyz's answer helped me in figuring out how to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872272/how-to-reference-another-property-in-java-util-properties?noredirect=1&lq=1)

If it helps anyone out there who is new to the world of coding,
In the class where the properties file is loaded and read I declared
private XProperties configFile = new XProperties();

I created another class for XProperties and copied in the code from GitHub [XProperties](https://github.com/MideO/CucumberJVM/blob/master/src/tests/cukes/stepdefinitions/config/XProperties.java)

Comment: Why do,'t you use `Apache Configuration` as sugested in my post?

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at Apache Configuration. It supports [Variable Interpolation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_basicfeatures.html#Variable_Interpolation).

If you like to set ENV_NAME as a **OS enviornment variable** `ENV_NAME=xyz` your property will be written like

```
LOGIN_URL=https://demo.testing.com/vp-clientlib-v1.php?env=${env:ENV_NAME}
```

If you set `ENV_NAME=xyz` as **property in the property file** than you would write

```
LOGIN_URL=https://demo.testing.com/vp-clientlib-v1.php?env=${ENV_NAME}
```

Beside this Apache Configuration provides a lot of other cool stuff for flexible property definition.

Comment: I've made my answer a bit more precisely to bring it more to the point of your question. But as already suggested, take a time to read Apache Configuration documentation.

Comment: Hey Stefan, Thank you so much for your response. I did the same where I declared ENV_HOME as another property in the properties file. But it failed to replace the  placeholder in the URL and the URL continued to be LOGIN_URL=https://demo.testing.com/vp-clientlib-v1.php?env=${ENV_NAME} as is. I am curious to know if we could do this but from what I read in other posts, properties file is just a collection of strings in a key value pairs, and there is no direct way to substitute the property value within the property file. I would be happy if I wrong and if it is infact possible to do so